# Error called object 'calculateTaxes' is not a function or function pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers, tax

here in my program i must ask the user for his total sales for the month, then ask the user for the county tax rate(6%) and the state sales tax(6%) then calculate the total sales tax based of what they entered. i also must utilize pointers.

i keep getting the following error:[Error] called object 'calculateTaxes' is not a function or function pointer

i cant seem to figure it out. here is the code i have so far

```
#include <stdio.h>

int inputTaxData(int* totalSales);
float calculateTaxes;
int main()


{
int* totalSales;
inputTaxData(&totalSales);
calculateTaxes();
float c;
float s;
float t;

    return 0;
}


int inputTaxData(int* totalSales)
{
printf("What is your total sales for the month?");
scanf("%d", totalSales);
}


float calculateTaxes(float c, float s, float t)
{
float c = 1.06;
float s = 1.06;
float t = c + s;
printf ("Your total state and county sales tax is %f", totalSales);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare `float calculateTaxes;`, i.e. as a float variable.
Then you try to call it as a function.

```
calculateTaxes();
```

That is what the compiler tries to tell you.
You probably wanted to instead provide a prototype for the later defined function.

```
float calculateTaxes(float c, float s, float t);
```

Comment: There are other issue with your code, which might cause it to fail doing what you expect. I trust however that you will find them yourself, or make corresponding separate questions.

Comment: i am aware i am missing some separate questions and will get those on there ASAP